# SQL calculations: Perform AVERAGE using THIS year, LAST year and NEXT year data?

Tags: sql, database

I’m struggling to recreate a certain calculation in SQL that I can do in Excel. It concerns averages.

We collect data over many years. One table we create is a three year average. Below are tables that show: 1) the RAW data, and 2) a new table with the AVERAGE data. The ‘Dimensions’ are [Year] & [ItemCode].

The average data is based on averaging a year’s figure with the 2 years either side. i.e. 1991 average figure = Average (1990,1991,1992). =AVERAGE(B2:D2)

1) RAW
[image]

2) AVERAGE

[alt text http://tinypic.com/images/404.gif](http://tinypic.com/images/404.gif)

In Excel this seems simple to do: an average formula that is then dragged into the other cells, or in VBA using R1C1 referencing.

But what is it in SQL? 
How do you say use ‘this’ year & the year before & the year after data?

Also, I realise that if there’s an empty cell it would throw my calculations, so how do you manage NULL values so it only calculates when there are three figures to use?...and then do it all again until finished (many years and many, many ItemCodes)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What SQL database are you using? What queries have you come up with so far and what is the problem with them? Can you post the code?

Comment: Also, what is the format of the database?

Comment: share your query that you have tried!

Comment: The database is a company bespoke one with limited access to the back end (calculations). It has some predefined functions: sum, average, etc, which we can use arguments within.

Comment: I haven't attempted anything complictaed yet with the calculations so I haven't got anything to show. We are currently using it to perform such things as: (Arg1/Arg2)*100; or IF 'ItemCode' in ('A123', 'B123') THEN (Arg1 + Arg3) / Arg2 * 100 ELSE Arg1 / Arg2 * 100. Quite basic stuff at the moment, hence my reqest for advice on how a more complicated query would look. Thanks.

Comment: @Mike - What is the structure of your actual tables? Are you actually planning to add a new column each year for example?

Comment: Our tables already have the years 2050+ inlcuded (built that way). The calculations on the imported data would populate a separate table that contains the same dimenions: Year & ItemCode.

Answer (score 0):

You don't state the technology, assuming MSSQL.

Assume mydate is 2010

```
SELECT dateadd(Year, -1, mydate), mydate, dateadd(Year, 1, mydate) 
   FROM SomethingOrOther
```

returns

```
2009, 2010, 2011
```

[DATEADD documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258267%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

Assume x, y, z are all NULL

```
SELECT COALESCE(x, y, z, 0)
```

returns

```
0
```

[COALESCE documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've got some reading to do. I'll need to ask our IT guys if we have access to such functions as dateadd or COALESCE. It may be that they have to do this query in the back end and make it available to me. y goal is to give them a push into making it by showing them the sturcture of the query.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an example below in which I average the value for year 1994 to get you started. The SQL query should work in any RDBMS. That said, each database has a better approach if you can use the vendor specific features. For example, using Oracle analytics you can compute a rolling average and access the prev/next row pretty much like wanted.

```
drop table t;

create table t(
   item_code varchar(10) not null
  ,year      int not null
  ,figure    decimal(5,2) not null
  ,primary key(year, item_code)
);

insert into t(item_code, year, figure) values('A', 1990, 5);
insert into t(item_code, year, figure) values('A', 1991, 7.2);
insert into t(item_code, year, figure) values('A', 1992, 9.2);
insert into t(item_code, year, figure) values('A', 1993, 12.5);
insert into t(item_code, year, figure) values('A', 1994, 10);
insert into t(item_code, year, figure) values('A', 1995, 9);

insert into t(item_code, year, figure) values('B', 1990, 16);
insert into t(item_code, year, figure) values('B', 1991, 17);
insert into t(item_code, year, figure) values('B', 1992, 10);
insert into t(item_code, year, figure) values('B', 1993, 13);
insert into t(item_code, year, figure) values('B', 1994, 15.5);
insert into t(item_code, year, figure) values('B', 1995, 12);

insert into t(item_code, year, figure) values('C', 1990, 4);
insert into t(item_code, year, figure) values('C', 1991, 9);
insert into t(item_code, year, figure) values('C', 1992, 15);
insert into t(item_code, year, figure) values('C', 1993, 12);
insert into t(item_code, year, figure) values('C', 1994, 10);
insert into t(item_code, year, figure) values('C', 1995, 7.2);



select item_code
      ,1994 as year
      ,sum(case when year = 1995 then figure else 0 end) as next_year
      ,sum(case when year = 1994 then figure else 0 end) as this_year
      ,sum(case when year = 1993 then figure else 0 end) as prev_year
      ,sum(figure) / count(*) as avg
  from t
 where year in(1993, 1994, 1995)
 group 
    by item_code
having count(*) = 3;
```

The **count(*) = 3** satisfies the constraint that an average will only be computed if there are three years available. Obviously, you have to replace the constants with some variable. Also, the query only computes the averages for 1 year.

Comment: @Mike, did you end up using it?